# How do I generate -1 V with 1 V?

Tags: voltage

I have a existing 1 V source.

How do I generate a -1 V base from this 1 V source?

An inverter won't help because it only flips 1 V to 0 V.

Comment: You're missing a lot of detail. How much current do you need on the -1 V output? How precise does it need to be? How efficient? How much ripple can be tolerated?

Comment: the 1V source is DC so I want the -1V output as DC as well , and as precise as it can be. but I can tolerate like 10% margin

Comment: How much power/current is required. Also, inverter means different things depending on context. In digital logic an inverter changes a logic HI to a logic LO, whatever those voltages are. In power electronics, an inverter can literally reverse the voltage polarity and is used to do things like drive/commutate motors, or produce AC sine waves from a DC source. But just because it can do it doesn't mean it's overkill. We need to know more.

Comment: Depending on your answers to Hearth's questions, maybe an inverting buck boost or a capacitive voltage inverter.

Comment: I don't care about the current, I just want it to be ideal -1V voltage source

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please edit your question (don't use comments) and add detail on what you're using this for, plus what the load currents are etc. It's not just going to be a 1-line answer.

Comment: @gibaicao An ideal voltage source can provide an infinite amount of current and maintain voltage without sagging. Obviously not possible. We need to know the amount of current you plan to pull: to power something small (10-20mA)? To power something large (>100mA. Maybe even >1A)? Miniscule amounts (like 1uA to 1mA) of current for use as a voltage reference? What exactly? Because if you literally mean you want as close to an ideal voltage source as you can afford then you are going to end up with a a high current voltage source since those put out the most current with the least voltage sag.

Comment: Insufficient requirements. Vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

1. Charge a capacitor with 1 V.
2. Disconnect both terminals
3. Connect the former +1 V terminal to GND
4. The former GND terminal will now offer a -1 V supply.

This is a charge pump voltage inverter, and there are ICs that perform all the steps for you.